# Sent command to remote desktop via BATCH file

Tags: windows, batch-file, desktop

I use a BATCH file on my work computer because I start everyday with the same programs and websites. Via this file I also login to my remote desktop where I also open a few programs every morning.

At the moment I use a BATCH file on the remote desktop to open everything there with 1 click. But I am wondering if it is possible to include these commands into my local BATCH file.

I guess it could be something like this??

```
@ECHO OFF
START C:\Users\redcoon.nl\Desktop\RemoteDesktop.rdp outlook.exe chrome.exe notepad.exe
```

The goals is that I click on my local BATCH file, and that it opens up my local programs, makes connection with the remote desktop and also opens a few program on the remote desktop.

Comment: `WMIC` with process verb and `SCHTASKS` are capable to execute commands on remote machine.There's also `PSEXEC` which is dedicated to remote executions but requires additional download

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid I'm not good enough at coding to understand how to use it. I guess SCHTASKS.exe would allow me to create a scheduled task, but not sure how to use this remotely? And I don't fully understand the documentation on WMIC.